# How to design model in Django using GeoDjango?

Tags: postgresql, geodjango, postgis-2.0

I am using Postgresql 9.0 and PostGIS 2.0. I am using Django 1.3 and GeoDjango. I have a model with `id`, `latitude`, `longitude` and `placename`. All the places are in the USA.

My requirement is following:

- User will give his address. We use his address to get latitude and longitude, and then find places within 'x' miles.

So, should I use `PointField` in the model? Also, how do I convert users latitude\longitude into geometry object to use `dwithin`?

Answer (score 3):

Your model must be like this:

```python
# Import django module
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Point(models.Model):
    placename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.name, self.geom.x, self.geom.y)
```

your view is :

```python
from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
from adress.models import Point
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D # ``D`` is a shortcut for ``Distance``

def AdressFinder(request):
    adress = request.POST.get('sentAdress', '')
    getAdressCoord = Point.objects.get(placename = str(adress))
    po = POINT(getAdressCoord.x getAdressCoord.y)
    pnt = fromstr(str(po), srid=4326)
    qs = Point.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=5)))

    return HttpResponse(your choose for returning object)
```

it will give you objects in 5 km square.

```
Geodjango Distance Lookups
Availability: PostGIS, Oracle, SpatiaLite

The following distance lookups are available:

distance_lt
distance_lte
distance_gt
distance_gte
dwithin
```

Don't forget, `qs` is in array and it filters all objects for your request that you have to loop for getting all objects one by one..

Now you can convert your result to GeoJSON or anything for your app...
I hope it helps you....

Comment: I have already done this but getting error when firing distance queries

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: first of all, you have to make geometry column in your db from your x and y. because of spaial query, you will need this...and give me some detail about your error...